# Feature Activation User

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, feature, feature-activation, feature-receiver

Which user context is used in feature activation receiver?

Is it current user (when activating from WebUI)?

I have to call a service in feature activation receiver and I have to know which user should have access to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feature activation from UI uses the current user context.

You can use elevated code if you want normal users to gain more privileges.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The same when I use powershell (does it use powershell current user)? Actually I thought so but I can't find any Microsoft official statement, do you know where can I find it?

Comment: @Greg Yes in Powershell also it uses the context of the application. I will look around for documentation.